# Network chart using Matplotlib with circles around groups of nodes

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm trying to draw like this chart in Python using `matplotlib`:

[image: desired plot]

I'm using the code provided here: https://python-graph-gallery.com/network-chart/

But I'm not able to draw the big circles that are around the groups of nodes (e.g. the brown circle at the left of the picture which contains time, search, services, etc.).

How can I draw these circles using `matplotlib`, or using any other library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use patches. It's described with examples on the [documentation of matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/patch_collection.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-patch-collection-py).

Comment: but it will be hard to make group members near to each other in the picture to draw the circle around them! The solution shouldn't be as a second layer on top of the network nodes.

Comment: Well, you asked how to draw the big circles. Anyway the code you provided is no longer supported by networkx.